# VBA / Excel - Replace value only if cell does not contain formula

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I'm attempting to use the replace function to change some values, however the way I'm currently doing it will change values in vital formula.

How can I have the replace function work only on cells with no formula, within one column? I tried If Not Columns("I").HasFormula Then but that prevents the replace from working on the entire column if a formula is found.

```
Columns("I").Replace What:="10", _
                            Replacement:="Five", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("I").Replace What:="9", _
                            Replacement:="Four", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("I").Replace What:="8", _
                            Replacement:="Three", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("I").Replace What:="7", _
                            Replacement:="Three", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("I").Replace What:="6", _
                            Replacement:="Two", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("I").Replace What:="5", _
                            Replacement:="Two", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("I").Replace What:="4", _
                            Replacement:="One", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("I").Replace What:="3", _
                            Replacement:="One", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("I").Replace What:="2", _
                            Replacement:="One", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("I").Replace What:="1", _
                            Replacement:="One", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
Sub replaceFormulas()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("I:I")
With rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    .Replace What:="9", Replacement:="Four", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    ' etc etc
End With
End Sub
```

If that works, next I suggest just using the workable range, as I doubt you have *every* cell in column I filled in.  Perhaps get the last row and do 
`Set rng = Range("I1:I" & lastRow)` to save a little time.

Note: This worked if I had cells with `9` and `="9"`. It just replaced `9` and kept my `="9"` there.

Comment: I might be tired, but I think the OP wants the exact opposite, not to modify cells with formulas

Comment: @ShaiRado - D'oh! No, you're not too tired, I'm just not feeling well. I misread that, you're right. I've updated to switch to `xlCellTypeConstants`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the quickest macro but you could iterate over each cell like this:

```
Sub fixCol_I()

Dim cell As Range
Dim iMatch As Integer
Dim strWhat As Variant
Dim strReplc As Variant
strWhat = Array("10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1")
strReplc = Array("Five", "Four", "Three", "Three", "Two", "Two", "One", "One", "One", "One")

For Each cell In Columns("I").rows
    If Not cell.HasFormula And cell <> "" Then
        For iMatch = 0 To UBound(strWhat)
            cell.Replace What:=strWhat(iMatch), _
                        Replacement:=strReplc(iMatch), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next iMatch
    End If
Next cell
```

End Sub